# Bash parse command into 2d array

Tags: linux, bash, midi

I want to make a script that lists all the available midi devices and prompts the user to choose one and then later on assign shortcuts to each note.
I managed to get a list of all the devices using the `aseqdump -l`. In my case, this outputs:

```
 Port    Client name                      Port name
  0:0    System                           Timer
  0:1    System                           Announce
 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 20:0    UMC404HD 192k                    UMC404HD 192k MIDI 1
 28:0    Launchpad S                      Launchpad S MIDI 1
```

and with my minimal skills I made a script that added a number before each line so it looks like this:

```
    Port    Client name                      Port name
 1) 0:0    System                           Timer
 2) 0:1    System                           Announce
 3) 14:0    Midi Through                     Midi Through Port-0
 4) 20:0    UMC404HD 192k                    UMC404HD 192k MIDI 1
 5) 28:0    Launchpad S                      Launchpad S MIDI 1
```

And then the user is prompted to pick a device based on the numbers on the left. All fun and games but i do not know how I could read the device name only. For example, if the user entered '4', i want my mDevice variable to be equal to "UMC404HD 192k", so that i can call `aseqdump -p $(mDevice)` and monitor its activity.

I tried reading the command output word by word but that seems to be useless since the number of words in each field varies anywhere from 1 to 5 or even more. Is it possible to parse the input of this command to a 2d array, where one dimension would store a device? For example, I would ideally have

```
mDevicesArray[0] = { "0:0", "System, "Timer"} 
mDevicesArray[1] = { "0:1", "System", "Announce"}
...
mDevicesArray[4] = { "28:0", "Launchpad S", "Launchpad S MIDI 1"}
```

and then use this array for further processing of the devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

bash doesn't have 2D arrays. You can simulate one with an associative array as long as speed of execution isn't a big deal:

```
$ cat ./tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

declare -A mDevicesArray

mDevicesSet() {
    local rowNr="$1" colNr
    shift
    for (( colNr=1; colNr<=$#; colNr++ )); do
        mDevicesArray["${rowNr},${colNr}"]="${!colNr}"
    done
}

mDevicesSet 1 '0:0'  'System'        'Timer'
mDevicesSet 2 '0:1'  'System'        'Announce'
mDevicesSet 3 '14:0' 'Midi Through'  'Midi Through Port-0'
mDevicesSet 4 '20:0' 'UMC404HD 192k' 'UMC404HD 192k MIDI 1'
mDevicesSet 5 '28:0' 'Launchpad S'   'Launchpad S MIDI 1'

printf '%s\n' "${mDevicesArray[4,2]}"

$ ./tst.sh
UMC404HD 192k
```

Otherwise there's various other workarounds, e.g. using `eval` which I wouldn't recommend or for simplicity, robustness, and efficiency you can just use `mDevicesArray1[1]="0:0"; mDevicesArray2[1]="System"; mDevicesArray3[1]="Timer"` and so on and trivially write functions to access the arrays as if they were 2D, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/bin/bash

mDevicesSet() {
    local rowNr="$1"
    shift
    mDevicesArray1["$rowNr"]="$1"
    mDevicesArray2["$rowNr"]="$2"
    mDevicesArray3["$rowNr"]="$3"
}

mDevicesGet() {
    local rowNr=$1 colNr=$2 val
    case $colNr in
        1 ) val="${mDevicesArray1[$rowNr]}" ;;
        2 ) val="${mDevicesArray2[$rowNr]}" ;;
        3 ) val="${mDevicesArray3[$rowNr]}" ;;
    esac
    printf '%s\n' "$val"
}

mDevicesSet 1 '0:0'  'System'        'Timer'
mDevicesSet 2 '0:1'  'System'        'Announce'
mDevicesSet 3 '14:0' 'Midi Through'  'Midi Through Port-0'
mDevicesSet 4 '20:0' 'UMC404HD 192k' 'UMC404HD 192k MIDI 1'
mDevicesSet 5 '28:0' 'Launchpad S'   'Launchpad S MIDI 1'

printf '%s\n' "$(mDevicesGet 4 2)"

$ ./tst.sh
UMC404HD 192k
```

Compared to using associative arrays, though faster to execute, the downsides to the indexed array approach are that you have a hard-coded number of columns (3) and every row must have the same number of columns and it's harder to expand upon to more than 2 indices.

Answer (score 1):

`aseqdump` lists only input ports, and the column output makes it hard to parse.

It would be easier to parse the output of `aconnect`, which has only one client or port per line, and uses delimiters:

```
$ aconnect -io
client 0: 'System' [type=kernel]
    0 'Timer           '
    1 'Announce        '
client 64: 'Rawmidi 0 - EMU10K1 MPU-401 (UART)' [type=kernel]
    0 'EMU10K1 MPU-401 (UART)'
client 65: 'Emu10k1 WaveTable' [type=kernel]
    0 'Emu10k1 Port 0  '
    1 'Emu10k1 Port 1  '
    2 'Emu10k1 Port 2  '
    3 'Emu10k1 Port 3  '
client 128: 'DMIDI' [type=user]
    0 'DMIDI - Receive: [ff:ff:ff:ff]'
    1 'DMIDI - Transmit [ff:ff:ff:ff]'
client 129: 'LinuxSampler' [type=user]
    0 'LinuxSampler    '
```

(If you actually want only input ports, use only `-i`.)